# Apache 2.4.12 https conversion

Tags: apache

I have  installed Apache 2.4.12 version with openssl version 1.0.1e. but we are not able to use TLSv1.2. Is there any additional library required?

How to check that apache is used this openssl during the installation?

Is there any way can during installation make sure that it uses the write ssl.

Comment: You configure the `https` protocol inside the apache http server configuration. There are many explanations about how to do that. If that succeeds, then you can be sure that ssl encryption is in place, since without ssl you cannot use the https protocol. You will also need a ssl certificate for that, though.

Comment: we have done the configuration as below                                         Listen 7733
PidFile logs/httpd_xxx.pid
TraceEnable Off
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite ALL
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile modules/xx_Certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile modules/xx_Certificate.key
LoadModule findna_module modules/mod_xxx.so .       we are able to see the apache "it works " message in browser.Is the any way  to determine that apache will be able handle the TLSv1.2 protocol?

Comment: Please use the `edit` button below your own question to add details. Thanks.